# Passing value to variables for each condition of IF ELSE conditional statements in- Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, parameter-passing

I am trying to build a classifier, where for each condition different weights is given.

```
if ( a >350 and a < 1000) AND (b>45 and b <75) or (c >65 and c < 100):
    print ("This is category A")
```

Now for each condition being true, I want to add a value to a variable.
like if first part `( a >350 and < 100)` is `True` , I want a variable `k=10`

and if second part `(b>45 and b <75)` is `True` , I want another variable `f=20` similarly `(c >65 and c < 100)` is `True` , I want another variable `q=80`.

If it is `False` for this condition put `q=0`

like this i want to create a percentage system for each category.

```
print(" percentage of this being class A-> ",k+f+q)
```

Comment: `( a >350 and a < 100)`: can you think of a value that satisfies these conditions?

Comment: my bad, i changed the value, now you can answer @CristiFati

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: actually i got it, we cannot do it in a single IF statement. I have to Create another user defined function where i evaluate each condition separately and add the k+f+q and return it.